# TypeScript - reposition elements in an array

Tags: typescript

I have following array that can have multiple elements in it.

```
"coachID" : [ 
     "choice1", 
     "choice2"
]
```

If user chooses choice2, I would like re-arrange its content as shown below.

```
"coachID" : [ 
     "choice2", 
     "choice1"
]
```

Similarly, if there are more than 2 elements in the array;

```
"coachID" : [ 
     "choice1", 
     "choice2",
     "choice3"
]
```

and user chooses choice2 element then array should be re-arranged as follows:

```
"coachID" : [ 
     "choice2", 
     "choice1",
     "choice3"
]
```

**In essence, chosen element should always be placed at the beginning of the array.**

How can I achieve this with TypeScript please?

Comment: Might be worthwhile tagging your question with [tag:javascript] as well. I don't think there's anything typescript-specific about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything TypeScript-specific about this.

You can just use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to take the selected element out, and [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add it back in at the beginning:

```
array.unshift(...array.splice(index, 1)); // index = index of the selected element
```

```js
const data = [ 
     "choice1", 
     "choice2",
     "choice3"
];

const select = (array, i) => {
  if (array && array.length && i < array.length) {
    array.unshift(...array.splice(i, 1));
  }
};

console.log(data);

select(data, 1);

console.log(data);
```

---

If you want to base the operation on the value of the selected element, add a call to [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
array.unshift(...array.splice(array.indexOf(value), 1)); // value = selected value
```

```js
const data = [ 
     "choice1", 
     "choice2",
     "choice3"
];

const select = (array, value) => {
  if (array && array.length) {
    const i = array.indexOf(value);
    
    if (i > 0) { 
      array.unshift(...array.splice(i, 1));
    }
  }
};

console.log(data);

select(data, "choice2");

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I hold the value that user has selected and I want to re-arrange the array using the selected value. I'm confused as to how this solution could be used for this scenario.

Comment: So you need to find the index of the selected value first? Use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks.